# Ubuntu Server 13.10: How to downgrade kernel

Tags: ubuntu, crash, kernel, downgrade

`Ubuntu Server 13.10` appears to be very unstable, I got random crashes of the system with no apparent reason and nothing is showing in syslog.

This is screenshot from the console when the crash occurred

[image]

Anyway I think it's actually caused by the new kernel 3.11. I would like to downgrade to 3.4 to check it. Is it possible?

`sudo aptitude search linux-image` indicates that only versions available I've is 3.11 kernel:

```
p   linux-image                                                     - Generic Linux kernel image.                                               
p   linux-image:i386                                                - Generic Linux kernel image.                                               
v   linux-image-3.0                                                 -                                                                           
v   linux-image-3.0:i386                                            -                                                                           
p   linux-image-3.11.0-11-lowlatency                                - Linux kernel image for version 3.11.0 on x86/x86_64                       
p   linux-image-3.11.0-11-lowlatency:i386                           - Linux kernel image for version 3.11.0 on x86/x86_64                       
i A linux-image-3.11.0-12-generic                                   - Linux kernel image for version 3.11.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP                   
p   linux-image-3.11.0-12-generic:i386                              - Linux kernel image for version 3.11.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP                   
p   linux-image-3.11.0-13-generic                                   - Linux kernel image for version 3.11.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP                   
p   linux-image-3.11.0-13-generic:i386                              - Linux kernel image for version 3.11.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP                   
p   linux-image-3.11.0-13-lowlatency                                - Linux kernel image for version 3.11.0 on x86/x86_64                       
p   linux-image-3.11.0-13-lowlatency:i386                           - Linux kernel image for version 3.11.0 on x86/x86_64                       
p   linux-image-3.11.0-14-generic                                   - Linux kernel image for version 3.11.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP                   
p   linux-image-3.11.0-14-generic:i386                              - Linux kernel image for version 3.11.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP                   
p   linux-image-3.11.0-14-lowlatency                                - Linux kernel image for version 3.11.0 on x86/x86_64                       
p   linux-image-3.11.0-14-lowlatency:i386                           - Linux kernel image for version 3.11.0 on x86/x86_64                       
p   linux-image-3.11.0-15-generic                                   - Linux kernel image for version 3.11.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP                   
p   linux-image-3.11.0-15-generic:i386                              - Linux kernel image for version 3.11.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP                   
p   linux-image-3.11.0-15-lowlatency                                - Linux kernel image for version 3.11.0 on x86/x86_64                       
p   linux-image-3.11.0-15-lowlatency:i386                           - Linux kernel image for version 3.11.0 on x86/x86_64                       
p   linux-image-3.4.0-1-goldfish:i386                               - Linux kernel image for version 3.4.0 on Android touch emulation           
i A linux-image-extra-3.11.0-12-generic                             - Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.11.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP           
p   linux-image-extra-3.11.0-12-generic:i386                        - Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.11.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP           
p   linux-image-extra-3.11.0-13-generic                             - Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.11.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP           
p   linux-image-extra-3.11.0-13-generic:i386                        - Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.11.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP           
p   linux-image-extra-3.11.0-14-generic                             - Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.11.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP           
p   linux-image-extra-3.11.0-14-generic:i386                        - Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.11.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP           
p   linux-image-extra-3.11.0-15-generic                             - Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.11.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP           
p   linux-image-extra-3.11.0-15-generic:i386                        - Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.11.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP           
p   linux-image-extra-virtual                                       - Transitional package.                                                     
p   linux-image-extra-virtual:i386                                  - Transitional package.                                                     
i A linux-image-generic                                             - Generic Linux kernel image                                                
p   linux-image-generic:i386                                        - Generic Linux kernel image                                                
p   linux-image-generic-pae:i386                                    - Transitional package                                                      
p   linux-image-goldfish:i386                                       - Linux kernel image for the goldfish kernel.                               
p   linux-image-lowlatency                                          - lowlatency Linux kernel image                                             
p   linux-image-lowlatency:i386                                     - lowlatency Linux kernel image                                             
p   linux-image-lowlatency-pae:i386                                 - Transitional package                                                      
p   linux-image-server                                              - Transitional package.                                                     
p   linux-image-server:i386                                         - Transitional package.                                                     
p   linux-image-virtual                                             - This package will always depend on the latest minimal generic kernel image
p   linux-image-virtual:i386                                        - This package will always depend on the latest minimal generic kernel image
```

apt-cache search linux-image

```
alsa-base - ALSA driver configuration files
linux-image - Generic Linux kernel image.
linux-image-3.11.0-12-generic - Linux kernel image for version 3.11.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
linux-image-extra-3.11.0-12-generic - Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.11.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
linux-image-extra-virtual - Transitional package.
linux-image-generic - Generic Linux kernel image
linux-image-server - Transitional package.
linux-image-virtual - This package will always depend on the latest minimal generic kernel image.
linux-virtual - Minimal Generic Linux kernel and headers
linux-image-generic-pae - Transitional package
linux-image-3.11.0-11-lowlatency - Linux kernel image for version 3.11.0 on x86/x86_64
linux-image-lowlatency - lowlatency Linux kernel image
linux-image-3.4.0-1-goldfish - Linux kernel image for version 3.4.0 on Android touch emulation
linux-image-goldfish - Linux kernel image for the goldfish kernel.
linux-image-lowlatency-pae - Transitional package
linux-image-3.11.0-13-generic - Linux kernel image for version 3.11.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
linux-image-3.11.0-14-generic - Linux kernel image for version 3.11.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
linux-image-3.11.0-15-generic - Linux kernel image for version 3.11.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
linux-image-extra-3.11.0-13-generic - Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.11.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
linux-image-extra-3.11.0-14-generic - Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.11.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
linux-image-extra-3.11.0-15-generic - Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.11.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
linux-image-3.11.0-13-lowlatency - Linux kernel image for version 3.11.0 on x86/x86_64
linux-image-3.11.0-14-lowlatency - Linux kernel image for version 3.11.0 on x86/x86_64
linux-image-3.11.0-15-lowlatency - Linux kernel image for version 3.11.0 on x86/x86_64
```

dpkg -l | grep linux

```
ii  libselinux1:amd64                   2.1.13-2                            amd64        SELinux runtime shared libraries
ii  libv4l-0:amd64                      0.8.9-4                             amd64        Collection of video4linux support libraries
ii  libv4lconvert0:amd64                0.8.9-4                             amd64        Video4linux frame format conversion library
ii  linux-firmware                      1.116                               all          Firmware for Linux kernel drivers
ii  linux-generic                       3.11.0.12.13                        amd64        Complete Generic Linux kernel and headers
ii  linux-headers-3.11.0-12             3.11.0-12.19                        all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.11.0
ii  linux-headers-3.11.0-12-generic     3.11.0-12.19                        amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 3.11.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-generic               3.11.0.12.13                        amd64        Generic Linux kernel headers
ii  linux-image-3.11.0-12-generic       3.11.0-12.19                        amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.11.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.11.0-12-generic 3.11.0-12.19                        amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.11.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-generic                 3.11.0.12.13                        amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
ii  linux-libc-dev:amd64                3.11.0-15.23                        amd64        Linux Kernel Headers for development
ii  util-linux                          2.20.1-5.1ubuntu9                   amd64        Miscellaneous system utilities
```

UPDATE

tried to install the kernel from 
http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.4-precise/

but ubuntu hangs at " Loading Initial Ramdisk"

UPDATE 2

looks like my system crashes are related to this bug: bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=734172
apparently fixed in 3.12.6, but again ubuntu hangs at " Loading Initial Ramdisk"

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to downgrade your version of Ubuntu, as those kernels are what's available in 13.10. Try [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DowngradeHowto#The_second_method).

Otherwise, you could try grabbing an older kernel version from a stable LTS version: http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.4-precise/

Ubuntu kernel information: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds

Comment: can't boot the system after reboot. ubuntu hangs at " Loading Initial Ramdisk"

Comment: Which route did you choose?

Comment: What do you mean by route?

Comment: As in, which of the options I listed above did you choose?

Comment: I tried to install 3.4 kernel... `http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.4-precise/` I'm afraid I'll completely mess ubuntu with the downgrade method.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/49869/how-to-roll-back-ubuntu-to-a-previous-version

could find some usefull information here.